# Pulling Serial Number from disconnected GPU

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, gpu, amd-radeon

I wanted to know if Windows saves teh serial number of attached hardware somewhere on the system. The GPU's in question have been disconnected and I am unable to check the GPU's themselve.

They however are still in Device Manager under hidden view, so I was hoping that I would somehow still be able to pull the serial number from them. They are newer GPU's R9 290 series if that helps.

The

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController GET Description,PNPDeviceID,SerialNumber
```

Does not work from the other superuser thread, I am hoping AMD has a log file somewhere with installed info like serial number and what not.

Comment: If you still have the boxes for the cards, they will probably have serial numbers on them.

Comment: Boxes have been tossed.

Comment: Try to find it on the device. As much I know such componenets have a sticker on it with serial number and other information. If not check it in the bill receipt there will be it.